# My rubber roof has developed a leak. Can it be fixed?

Tags: roof, roofing

Anyone out there who could give me some advice please? I've got a rubber roof and it has developed a leak. It is small, yet fairly centralised. Can it be repaired, or have I got to replace the whole thing?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the best way (in my case) was to make a small incision to get a patch behind or underneath the sheet glued on with plenty of rubber cement, and then put a larger patch over the top with a generous amount of rubber cement, smoothing the edges with glue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check Walmart for flex seal.  Some of them do say OK for EDPM roof.  I got a tube of caulk like flex seal for $7; clearance and it says for EDPM.  The tape does too.